# Real diferença entre os métodos Call e Apply

Tags: javascript

Qual a diferença entre os métodos `call` e `apply`? Não consegui identificar a diferença em que um separa os argumentos e o outro gera um vetor para os argumentos:

```
function scope() {
        console.log(this, arguments.length);
    }
    scope() // window, 0
    scope.call("foobar", [ 1, 2 ]); // "foobar", 1
    scope.apply("foobar", [ 1, 2 ]); // "foobar", 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A diferença está no parâmetro que eles usam. Enquanto o [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) irá passar para a função uma array, o [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) irá passar valores individuais separados por vírgula:

O seu exemplo mostra isso:

```
scope.call("foobar", [ 1, 2 ]);
                     --------
                         ↑
                apenas 1 parâmetro
               arguments.length = 1


scope.apply("foobar", [ 1, 2 ]);
                      --------
                          ↑
                1 array com 2 itens
               arguments.length = 2
```

Outro exemplo de `call`:

```
scope.call("foobar", [ 1, 2 ], 3);
                     --------  -
                         ↑     ↑
                      2 parâmetros
                   arguments.length = 2
```

O `apply` não gera um vetor, ele envia um vetor como segundo parâmetro para a função. Exemplo:

```js
function scope() {
   for(var item of arguments){
      console.log(item);
   }
}
scope.apply("foobar", ['abc','def','ghi']);
```

Documentação MDN sobre `apply`:

> **Note:** While the syntax of this function is almost identical to that of `call()`, the fundamental difference is that `call()` accepts an
>   **argument list**, while `apply()` accepts a **single array of arguments**.

Tradução livre:

> **Nota:** Embora a sintaxe desta função seja quase a mesma do `call()`, a diferença fundamental está em que `call()` aceita uma
>   **lista de argumentos**, enquanto que `apply()` aceita **um simples array com argumentos**.

O mesmo exemplo acima usando `call`:

```js
function scope() {
   for(var item of arguments){
      console.log(item);
   }
}
scope.call("foobar", ['abc','def','ghi']);
```

Note que o argumento `['abc','def','ghi']` chega na função com uma array inteira. Ao contrário de `apply`, que envia cada item do vetor como um argumento separado.

Comment: Entendi, mas, por que então usar `call` se ele não vai retornar o array corretamente? Para que ele existe?

Comment: Ele pode enviar um array, pode enviar outros argumentos que não seja array etc... ele vai tratar cada argumento de forma separada... com apply você só pode enviar array... no último exemplo, veja que ele envia a array normal, mas não lê diretamente os itens da array como faz o apply. Por exemplo: `scope.call("foobar", 1,2,3);` é igual a `scope.apply("foobar", [1,2,3]);`... Aí vai depender da sua aplicação, vc pode usar uma coisa ou outra... vc quer enviar uma array pra função tratar, use apply... quer enviar argumentos em separado, use call.

Comment: Certo, entendi man. Obrigado!

Answer (score 3):

Infelizmente o seu exemplo não foi o melhor. Começo primeiro por alterar o exemplo para mostrar os `arguments` por completo e não apenas o seu `length`:

```js
function scope() {
    console.log(this, JSON.stringify(arguments));
}

scope.call("foobar", [ 1, 2 ]); // "foobar", 1
scope.apply("foobar", [ 1, 2 ]); // "foobar", 2
```

Atente bem na diferença entre dos dois.

No caso do `call` os `arguments` são:

```
{"0":[1,2]}
```

Ou seja `1` argumento que é um array `[1,2]`, mas no  no `apply` vemos:

```
{"0":1,"1":2}
```

Que são `2` argumentos, o primeiro é `1` e o segundo é `2`.

Ou seja no `call` o array é todo passado como um só parâmetro, mas no `apply` o array indica os parâmetros a ser passados como se os tivesse escrito manualmente.

Então no seu caso fazer:

```
scope.apply("foobar", [1,2]);
```

Seria equivalente a fazer:

```
foobar(1 , 2);
```

Expandindo ainda mais no mesmo, fazer:

```
scope.apply("foobar", [1,2,3,4,5]);
```

Corresponderia a:

```
foobar(1 , 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

Assim vemos bem que é diferente de chamar a função com `call`.

### Cenários Reais

**Apply**

É util em quando você tem um array de elementos a passar a uma função, mas essa função não espera um array mas sim elementos separados e escritos diretamente.

Um caso evidente disso é o `Math.max` para calcular o máximo de entre vários números:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3 ,4, 5];

console.log(Math.max(arr));
console.log(Math.max.apply(null, arr));
```

`Math.max(arr)` não funciona porque `max` não suporta receber um array diretamente. `Math.max` está à espera de receber os elementos soltos, assim:

```
Math.max(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Que é exatamente o que o `apply` faz. Repare também que indiquei `null` como primeiro parâmetro que é o parâmetro que irá servir de `this` na função, e neste caso nós não queremos nenhum `this`.

**Call**

O call é comum de ser utilizado em "herança" no estilo antigo de Javascript sem as palavras reservadas `class` e `super`.

Vou pegar no exemplo do MDN, que certamente pode não ser o melhor, mas ainda assim é usado exatamente neste contexto. Imagine que tem uma função `Produto` para construir produtos e tem depois outra para `Comida` em que `Comida` seria uma extensão de `Produto`.

A chamada a `Produto` dentro do construtor de `Comida` normalmente seria feita com `call`:

```js
function Produto(nome, preco) {
  this.nome = nome;
  this.preco = preco;
}

function Comida(nome, preco) {
  Produto.call(this, nome, preco);
  this.categoria = 'comida';
}


let queijo = new Comida('feta', 5);
console.log(queijo);
```

Documentação:

- [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)
- [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

Comment: Legal cara, muito bem explicado!